# iptables port forwarding works only for localhost

Tags: iptables

Below is my iptables config. I used this for my accessing a node js website running in port 9000 through port 80. This works fine only if access the website through local host / loop back. When I try to use the ip of eth0, which is assigned by my router through dcp. this does not work, when I use ip like 192.168.0.103 to access the website. I am not able to figure what is wrong here, Already burnt a day in this, still not able to figure out :(

Edit: ( more information)
Earlier, I was using this configuration to develop the website, i had configured the domain name to point to 127.0.0.1 in the /etc/hosts file. It was working fine, but now I am trying to deploy the website in a vps with static ip, This configuration does not work with both static IP.

```
# redirect port 80 to port 9000
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [57:3896]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [4229:289686]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [4239:290286]
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 9000
COMMIT

#  Allow HTTP and HTTPS connections from anywhere (the normal ports for websites and SSL).
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9000 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -j REJECT
```

[EDIT:2: working configuration]

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [51:17434]
:INPUT ACCEPT [51:17434]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [239:16027]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [247:16507]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.1.59/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
-A PREROUTING -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
-A OUTPUT -d 192.168.1.59/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
COMMIT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iptables is doing exactly what you asked it to do. When traffic comes from another computer, the PREROUTING chain is consulted. When traffic is generated by your local computer, the OUTPUT chain is consulted. So let's look at your OUTPUT rule. You've written it to only apply to traffic where the destination is a loopback address. That's why it redirects 127.0.0.1:80 but not 192.168.0.103:80. You could add a second rule where the destination argument is set to `-d 192.168.0.103/32` and it would do what you want, but when your IP address changes you'll need to change the rule. A better approach might be to match traffic destined for your loopback interface, e.g.

```
-A OUTPUT -o lo -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8000
```

That should match both your loopback address and whatever is your current address assigned by dhcp.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot. It works if i change as you suggested, but then all the other routing are screwed, if i type any site in browser it just routes me to the local website. I modified the nat rules to specify -d ( please see EDIT 2 in question) then it works. I have 2 more questions, 1.nat is only for a packet that creates a new connection, does that mean it applies to new connections to localhost also? 2. in the OUTPUT chain, we are redirecting the the output in port 8000 to port 80 right? but we specify --dport as 80 and redirect as 8000. why so?

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/197426/how-does-the-iptables-chain-output-work. Answer by DerfK in this question, explains this very well. Unfortunately, I do not have reputation to upvote this

Comment: I revised my answer to avoid matching too much traffic.